# Method to find posts in children categories

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails

I use the gem act_as_votable to allow users to select categories they like. To get the categories a user likes:

```
 current_user.get_voted(Category)
```

These categories have children categories, and I need to find the posts in those children categories.

I use this line to do it:

```
@categories_posts = current_user.get_voted(Category).flat_map { |category| category.children.flat_map(&:posts)}.delete_if{ |post| post.status == "draft"}
```

But I noticed in my logs that this was doing way too much computation for this task.

Is there a way to make it lighter ?

Answer (score 1):

Some notes:

- You should limit the lines to 80/100 chars.
- When a call chain seems to include too much logic, move it to methods/class-methods of models.

As a first refactor, I'd implement `Category#with_children` and then write:

```
@categories_posts = current_user.
  get_voted(Category).
  flat_map(&:with_children).
  flat_map(&:posts).
  reject { |post| post.status == "draft" }
```

On a second refactor, it's nice to have relations instead of arrays as output. This way you can use scopes, paginators and such, even if you cannot directly use `has_many` here (because of the recursive category requirement):

```
categories = current_user.get_voted(Category).flat_map(&:with_children)
@categories_posts = Post.where(category: categories).published
```

That's to show the implementation, on the controller you should still have less logic, something like this: `@categories_posts = current_user.posts_of_voted_categories.published`.

Comment: Thanks for your input ! This indeed makes the code more readable, but does it make it more efficient ?

Comment: Updated, now it should be more efficient, it's using SQL from the category level.